# How to rename library .a product file name in Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, xcode, target, file-rename

I downloaded the following repository from GitHub:

https://github.com/zwaap/hello-int-pinvoke/tree/master/src/HelloInt.Native

I tried renaming my project to something with "lib" in the name by clicking on the project name and renaming it.  Xcode asked me if I wanted to rename everything.  I did so.  Now the .a file under "Projects" has the prefix "liblib" in front it.  I think Xcode automatically adds "lib" in front of .a files that it builds, but for some reason because I added "lib" to the project name no matter what I try to rename it to now the "lib" prefix is added twice.

Clicking on the product's file name doesn't help as it doesn't allow me to modify it there.  I have tried doing it within "Manage Schemes" but double clicking on Targets there doesn't help either.

Is there a way to fix this without having to manually edit the project files with a text editor?

Comment: change product name in Xcode build settings

Comment: Could you provide details?

Answer (score 2):

Target > Packaging > Executable Prefix > "lib" to "" or the first part you want on the library

Target > Packaging > Product Name > "nameyouwant"

Output library
"ExecutablePrefix"+"ProductName"+".a"